# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist while trying to access azure from spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

Below is my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("demoApp").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net", <account_key>)

val baseDir = "wasb://<container-name>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/"

val df = spark.read.orc(baseDir+"path")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist wasb://<container-name>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/path
```

Comment: Was the below answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking the following [**documentation**](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html).

they provided examples on how to read from Blob storage account using standard spark API and databricks API, the code shown is as below:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")

dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
```